# How to convert a tuple type to a union?

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics, union-types, mapped-types

How to map a tuple generic type to a union type?

```ts
type NeededUnionType<T> = T[keyof T]; // Includes all the Array properties values
  
const value: NeededUnionType<[7, string]> = 2; // This should not be allowed (2 is the tuple length)
```

Expected type: `7 | string`

Comment: type UnionFromTuple = TupleType[number];

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can index by `number` instead of `keyof T`. `keyof T` will contain all keys of the tuple object which includes the length as well as any other array properties.

```
type NeededUnionType<T extends any[]> = T[number]; // Includes all the Array properties values

const value: NeededUnionType<[7, string]> = 2; // err value is 7 | string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAchEBNEFUB2BLA9qgKuCAPDlBAB7ASoIDOUAhqiANoC6AfFALxQ5OoCuAWwBGEAE4sA3FAD0MqAElUAYwA2-JLTqrVUYAAtoAQTFi6IKGDGZIY4Ogi0Abtv6OAsACgvy7NWBQLuoQAFyw8EgIaFi4+ARMAOwANFD+YuioAObsXFAATNJyJKaBrtDotAlQAD6pwOlZUF5AA)

Comment: Is T[number] as a means to query all array members documented?  Does this imply other expressions are possible, like T[string] to query all object members?

Comment: @michaeljsalo Consider [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and see if you figure it out :)