# Typescript Conditionally required type using recursion

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've been struggling with this one all day, I'm new to typescript and trying to conditionally require an object property when a particular value is present in an array.

Here is link generator. Only Pinterest cares about an image URL, so I would like to require it if 'pinterest' is within the array of platforms.

```
type share = 'facebook' | 'pinterest' | 'twitter'

interface shareProps {
    pageTitle: string;
    platforms: share[];
    url: string;
    description: string;
}

interface propsWithImage extends shareProps {
    image: string;
}

type hasPinterest<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer U, ...infer V]
    ? U extends 'pinterest'
        ? propsWithImage
        : hasPinterest<V>
    : shareProps

function fn <T extends shareProps> (props: hasPinterest<T['platforms']>): string[] {
    const { platforms, url, description } = props
    const shareLinks: string[] = []
    platforms.forEach((platform) => {
        if (platform === 'pinterest') {
            shareLinks.push(`https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=${props.url}&media=${props.image}&description=${props.description}`)
        }
        if (platform === 'facebook') {
            shareLinks.push(`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${props.url}`)
        }
        if (platform === 'twitter') {
            shareLinks.push(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${props.description}`)
        }
    })
    return shareLinks
}

let shouldRequireImage = fn({
    pageTitle: 'Cool page',
    platforms: ['facebook', 'pinterest'],
    url: 'http://www.example.org',
    description: 'A really cool page',
    image: 'AwesomeImage.jpg'
})

let shouldNotRequireImage = fn({
    pageTitle: 'Cool page',
    platforms: ['facebook', 'twitter'],
    url: 'http://www.example.org',
    description: 'A really cool page',
})

console.log(shouldRequireImage)
console.log(shouldNotRequireImage)
```

hasPinterest appears to always be giving the type of shareProps when using the generic with 'platform' index. What am I missing?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=44&pln=20&pc=56#code/C4TwDgpgBAzgFgQwE7QLxQOQDMEGMIBGA9kQNYZQA+mYAlgHbAQozAXUbADutwTSGAFCCG-HPliIUABSREwMKAG9BUNVDAIA5hAAqvADYQAXLGBIGWgNyr1YAwmBYiSALYxT8ZBADaAXRt1KABXJANPc0tA9QATCBhcCzBgWiJ6CIt6a0EAX2FRZnFoMDkFAHVeOABJV21oCAAPJnoYxS8ZUsUVINpanQyo3OFQSChEGGkClmAAHl0oRubWqAR6EH8APih0ecWIFsUfBixmKABVABooADpb49OANT9bNQB+c4Wm-eWMOkZmeJsF5BKDvEryGAVYDVPoQYFBUzjSb-aYzB4bYGeKQQWQQ4RYYL0XApNJQLD0KBzT5LNrY3EKLYACnBCkRCAmU0Bcx8vwcThc7gwfg2AEoBll-Mpgbg0qxlBo+c43DArqEDFc4gkkiSKTlthpOtLZcBJN4ADIMUgeMyZLSS9D+YH2RxK9zXJUAUTwcEZzMVApF2y23RBaloWCgfpdAu2qHQv05rAwgZDoaC7QgFvoVuuYGC8EZAAM4HxWQB6Mt-fiA64y1yVhhlxIQRwQMsEYJ8NJl15q1AAEiULJg1zVOQAZK4IDFaAgB0POtdenUJ5rErRkql6PPh9c19qtzlCyL4eo8mmoOHI87+W5Y-GisQyMmpRf09iszm8wXi6WPBWuEA908EIEhSFrIh6wzJAy2g3M4DAXsd0XMdj1PNRzzTK8o1vVx70wbheH4F9UzfDNPxHb8fV-YByzLQi+GYCD6wKRh6K4CAIGAV4mCaZCIT3eJ103NIjxPC9MIw8T1BQYBQgpcjLRgIZBCME14CIYIDBiAAlCAAEdgloFAajqfVyUZUjNB0fRgCMUwMAAYRIAwNDqDALidf1lVMHlHzAjyaETNg-E8oI1QcktaOMACgMaBBXHsCBrhcLQPOBfcNx1ByAEEoBQBADAMEAoBlIhXOsiB0p6WFco4mBIIgUydGuAArMA0tyE9VK4yRNO0gA5IhgD0wzjKa2FzPoSynTqWz7MwZzyrcnRqrsbz3F87AQKfcgrk4HhGIEULgQizAorAGKy0ArhrnixKjBSpA0rC2IhIPNJcvylsipKsqKvczycm6mV6Aax6DCILRGQ0rTdIMoyTNhE9QfB5LIeh2HBuG0bEYmuoRSAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No recursion is necessary here.  The trick is just extracting the value of `platforms` and determining--in TypeScript--whether it contains `pinterest`.  To do that I use a handy little utility from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239632/how-to-convert-a-tuple-type-to-a-union):

```js
type NeededUnionType<T extends any[]> = T[number];
```

That lets us convert the `platforms` array to a union and then we just determine if `pinterest` extends that union.

```js
type HasPinterest<T extends Share[]> = 'pinterest' extends NeededUnionType<T> ? SharePropsWithImage<T> : SharePropsWithoutImage<T>
```

Then we just need to define your `props` types in a way that allows easily extracting the precise type of `platforms` using a generic type, extract that, and pass it to the helper function.

Here's the full solution:

```js
type Share = 'facebook' | 'pinterest' | 'twitter'

type SharePropsWithoutImage<T extends Share[]> = 
{
    pageTitle: string;
    platforms: T;
    url: string;
    description: string;
  } 

type SharePropsWithImage<T extends Share[]> = 
{ 
    pageTitle: string;
    platforms: T;
    url: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
  }

type ShareProps<T extends Share[]> = SharePropsWithImage<T> | SharePropsWithoutImage<T>

type NeededUnionType<T extends any[]> = T[number];

type HasPinterest<T extends Share[]> = 'pinterest' extends NeededUnionType<T> ? SharePropsWithImage<T> : SharePropsWithoutImage<T>

function fn <T extends Share[]> (props:HasPinterest<T>): string[] {
    // the code...
}
```

With a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQwE7QLxQOQDMEGMIBGA9kQNYZQA%20mYAlgHbAQoDOwF1GwA7rcE0gwAoIaEixEKAApIiYFgHU%20cIgFdgASQC2CAOYQAPABUoEAB5N6AExYTkEANoBdAHxR0QgN5CovqGD0IIz4AGwgALig2JAZdAG4fPzAQhGAsIiQtFkijBL8oVSQQyOjYvL8rCBZcGLBgWiJ6EuAY%20njEgF8oETFoeHsZOUVlbUDjUwsIa1t%20lGc3D09u-ID9YOAw5tb2lZS0jKyc8t9C4qiWssTfSura%20saty-zaHX1HtvKOnvA%20yQhB%20TjcyWGx2Oaudxg-6yeRKYBwUb6YxuaizaFDOEqdSIwxGFzfcQAOQgEEqVgAqvQGvQjD8gZNplAEPQQPNIUYHPRVFoCMwnAlRD8oAAJBAsKQMARVYD0kEzP5s9AYOiMZjSijAqag4mk0mU6m0yDIqAAfihAOG8JxxsiaItmLUmleuPxQiwqnouHu9CgWB9sq18vsbIAFGAYdlReLJWq2MiAJTvXTOKDefK4RpsVP%20PbpTIsAA0BSKRZuNVodWpUC66HDQyuUAz9CzLD%20ABkGKRsudtin0M4G8lUnmsgA6PMAUTwcBDYdzB3j7jcafyfloWCgc%20HB3cqCVKqlbAwi5Xq9XrfsHfoXdHYFUrZDAAM4Px5OEAPTvg%20x4CjjNaL8GHfGoIFSCB3wIdRgEad8TVOVAABJPDreRR1ODoADItFJWgEEQ5CI1HF5Akwss7mpfCUJYUcyIrb0OkfeMG3yL4z18ddNyHfZMl3JUcHwYgyGPVNmLYi8UCvG87wfZ9X2yT9uEU8c8EIEhSD-IgAPE5h320pBbzgMA4Mowj0MY0TfFYtiOK3bitF4zAeD4ARhNPNjfG0yTqOkmdZOAN9Pyc-hmA0gCY0Yd8eBJYATSYCwTKGGiqnLStGgYpj3KsyyMr8FBgEKH1PM7FghC%20IQwmAKIsRCKwACUIAAR1UWgUBxSE-RDNzViCUIIkwABhEgQn8QIMALQd53zSIHGwFTBPIItlRjVh2Cccb8lOSIMBffyP3fRTuFHcwEC0ZIIFHDJdDGhtaNSppMAAQSgFAEBCEIQEbIaRv0a7nmdSIACIHu4KpNPOgArMBdAB0qmPKiBKtbNQaoAMQQWgQgAIQgXAEHvCB6qalqIDa9AOq6wJ1k2Aavu636kkmw4oBm-jVKExbvxWjA1obTbMB2sA9oOo6zBOs6LqQK71oqZLyIeR7ntAt6PozIhhrp8aOjhiqquRqxCSIYBCea1rnXa%20hOsHSneq2wa1e%20iB6d8LiR27Fm5rUsbHN4YLBDW5Y-D57bXyFpTjtOsIJalm7Zbo6ktqel7lc%20%202NdhkQdaR1RUfRrGcbxlgIANo3GpNkmzbJi2KbWG2adT0bpedxm3dmgTPcWoKXP93mii2gXQ8O8Pxcup2oFu70E8V173pT9WG4bYi3kwFgwcXiGofToQmxXyOQiIXQQyzmrjeJnEmO3tXzr3g%20j-1w2T9NwJ4yAA).

Let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: Nice, I'll have to remember that array to union conversion trick! Thanks for your answer @sam256!