# How to check if tuple includes a particular type inside a conditional type?

Tags: typescript

As of TypeScript 4.2, it's [trivial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) to check if a tuple type begins or ends with a specific type:

```js
type HeadIsString<T extends any[]> = T extends [string, ...any[]] ? true : false;

type TailIsString<T extends any[]> = T extends [...any[], string] ? true : false;
```

However, I'd like to check if a tuple includes a particular type at any position in the tuple. Something like this is not currently possible

```js
type IncludesString<T extends any[]> = T extends [...any[], string, ...any[]] ? true : false;
```

because a tuple cannot have more than one rest element. The only solution I can think of is to [turn the tuple into a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239632/how-to-convert-a-tuple-type-to-a-union) first.

```js
type IncludesString<T extends any[]> = string extends T[number] ? true : false;
```

My specific use case is, given an array of functions, knowing if any of them return a Promise. For this specific use case, the above solution is sufficient. However, I could see other scenarios where this approach would *not* work. For example, where tuple elements could themselves be unions, but a type like `string | null` would be undesirable. So in this example, `[number, string | null]` would be transformed into `number | string | null` and the type would evaluate to `true`.

To clarify, I'm looking for a type that would, in our example, evaluate as follows:

```js
IncludesString<[]> // false
IncludesString<[number]> // false
IncludesString<[[string]]> // false
IncludesString<[string, number]> // true
IncludesString<[number, string, number]> // true
```

The use of `string` in this example is arbitrary -- I'm just looking for a generic approach that would avoid the aforementioned issue with using a union.

Comment: What do you mean by "elegant" here?  Do you want `IncludesString<[string | number]>` to be `true` or `false`?  What about `IncludesString<["abc"]>`?  It's possible [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJy3Dm) is what you want, but it really depends on use cases that you haven't quite articulated.  Please consider clarifying in the question.

Comment: Can you not just write an interface or class method for a subclass of tuple?

Comment: More edge cases... `IncludesString<[string]|[number]>` is what?  `IncludesString<[]>` is what?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, I've updated the question to provide additional clarity. The solution you provided is clever and indeed what I was looking for! If you'd like to convert your comment to an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance; probably not for a little while though; it's getting to be my bed time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possible approach:

```
type IncludesString<T extends any[]> =
    { [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends string ? unknown : never }[number] extends
    never ? false : true;
```

The idea is that we want to [map the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) type `T` to another tuple, where we turn anything extending `string` into [the `unknown` "top" type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), and anything not extending `string` into [the `never` "bottom" type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  So, for example, `[string, number, string | number, "abc"]` would be transformed into `[unknown, never, never, unknown]`, since both `string` and `"abc"` extend `string`, while both `number` and `string | number` do not.

Once we have that mapped tuple, we [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `number` to get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the elements of the mapped tuple.  In the previous example, that's `[unknown, never, never, unknown][number]`, which becomes `unknown | never | never | unknown`, which becomes `unknown`.  TypeScript immediately collapses any union of the form `A | unknown` to `unknown`, and any union of the form `A | never` to `A`.  That means when you union together a bunch of types which are either `unknown` or `never`, the outcome will be `unknown` if at least one of the input types is `unknown`, and the outcome will be `never` if none of the input types is `unknown`.

And because we have transformed the tuple so that anything extending `string` becomes `unknown` and anything not extending `string` becomes `never`, the resulting union will be `unknown` if and only if there's at least one member of the original tuple that extends `string`.

So now all we have to do is map `unknown` to `true` and `never` to `false`.  We do that with `extends never ? false : true` (since `unknown extends never` is false, and `never extends never` is true).

---

Let's test it out:

```
type X0 = IncludesString<[]> // false
type X1 = IncludesString<[number]> // false
type X2 = IncludesString<[[string]]> // false
type X3 = IncludesString<[string, number]> // true
type X4 = IncludesString<[number, string, number]> // true
type X5 = IncludesString<[string | number]>; // false
type X6 = IncludesString<["abc"]> // true
type X7 = IncludesString<[string] | [number]> // true?
```

Most of those are exactly the output you wanted.  The last one, though, `IncludesString<[string] | [number]>` is `true`, and it's not clear if that's what you want.  Perhaps you want `true | false` as the output.  Or maybe `false`.  Who knows?  There are always plenty of edge cases involved in custom type functions like this, and the only way to deal with that is to test thoroughly against your actual use cases and tweak the definition accordingly.  But I consider that outside the scope of the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwDYFcAmEDOBlYAnASzgHMAeAFSggA9gI41MoBDOEAbQF0A+KAXgCwAKCiioAbyjsYUIlADWEEAHsAZlHKcAXBumcqteoyiZ8RYlAD8UFHHlxlAdzhQdcCADcIeKAF92cCgAtgBG3vo0dAyYwmJQ7l4+1qrMSJjQOvgoEADcwsKgkFAAGgAM-LCIqBg4ZiSkXLwA9E1QKWkQBeDQxQCMFfDI6Fi4hPUBwWF4PFAtbanpXUXFAEwDVcO1Y2Ts7KbbnDNz7YtChT0AzOtDNaPmDfvmADTxk+HNrVmdZ90lACzXaojOo7QKhbwvR4kF5gqZHT54bJLHoAVkBmzu4yhFgAPq9wdNuDlZq0Tt9ziUAGzo24ghoAImYIQQ9PhUC+yJKAHYacDtg8Qfo8RMCWyvpYgA)

Comment: As a suggestion to others, I was able to use this same technique to check if a given string was included in a tuple of strings, which in my case helped me with a complex type guard