# Supporting multiple properties on a functions inside a `.d.ts` file

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-declaration

I am creating a typescript declaration file for a library written in JavaScript, for this task i am experiencing one problem over and over again. The JavaScript Library in question repeats the following pattern in a number of places.

```js
const commandList = [
  "run-like-nuts",
  "some-more-commands",
  "another-nice-command",
  "power-commmand",
  // lots more commands like this
  // in this list 
];


function commandRunner(...args) {
  // Does some internal work based on ...args 
  // returns type Promise<string>
}

commandList.forEach(command => {
  Object.defineProperty(commandRunner, command, {
    value: function(command, ...args) {
      return commandRunner(command, ...args);
    }
  )); 
});
```

How can i define types for the `commandRunner` function so that when I make use of it in typescript it is callable and it has properties in the `commandList`, which as is evident from the above example also become callable.

By attempt thus far given my limited grasp of typescript has been the following attempt but this does not resolve the problem. How can i resolve this ?

```
type ArgsType: string | Object;

type commandList = [
  "run-like-nuts",
  "some-more-commands",
  "another-nice-command",
  "power-commmand",
  // lots more commands like this
  // in this list 
];

export default (function commandRunner(...args: ArgsType[]) {}) & {
  [command: Command]: (command: Command,...args: ArgsType[]) => Promise<string>
}
```

Comment: What is the `Command` type? Also from my understanding only the `commandRunner` does take a command as its first parameter, the methods would not, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the `commandList` as an array so we can use it both at runtime and at compile time. To make the string literals available to use for the typing, we have to define it with `as const`.

```
const commandList = [
  "run-like-nuts",
  "some-more-commands",
  "another-nice-command",
  "power-commmand",
  // lots more commands like this
  // in this list 
] as const;
```

For the type of `commandRunner` we can map over the string literals in `commandList`.

```
type CommandRunner = ((...args: ArgsType[]) => Promise<string>) & { 
  [Command in typeof commandList[number]]: 
    (command: Command,...args: ArgsType[]) => Promise<string> 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggJwOYGcAqlYF4YpAgSwDskYAfGAeQCMArKAYxAG5hgGB7IvGTgWz4BDIgBMAMgR44A2sBgwARAgCuRALQAbAgGsoaospAoFAGjmKUHPnr4cEe-kNHGz8hcI4gAFlAT6CDA5WTiKm5goQHADuvmqOIWHyAPRJMBqeKDC29rzBwiKZWrow3pLmKTDEJV6SaZIgMMAAujCCmZzcLGzg0DAAwnmiAEqqRL4wOAAUkwB0c4LIKABc8IsY0NJNAJQTAHwwAAoIVpJQADx4hCS7OwBkMADejfLSAwL5lUQlmBwAZrnvUQSPDSAx8ai%20JpNFaTRz5FZvEImOYzBaoFaIVDrKCbHZYfZHE4oc6XYhIfbAAC%20bA6PDhw1GvgRgxEIyIYwQE0elNamWEYDY7C4PHsmRw9NZjIQ0iUqk0Oj0BiMCiawAq8hgAD0APxAA)

Comment: Hi there ! thanks for answering can you please explain what this expression means [Command in typeof commandList[number]] apart from this everything is clear.

Thanks !

Comment: we can use `typeof commandList` to get the type of the variable `commandList` which in this case is a tuple of multiple string literals. We can [index this tuple with `number`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59239690/8613630) to get a union of the string literals inside this tuple. This union can be used to create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) were we iterate over the elements in the union to create an object.